# Advice on STL data structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am implementing a display algorithm where we can have multiple layers of windows based on their z-order i.e. I start with the last z-value and merge the images until we have the image with the z-value as 0 at the top. 
To maintain the z-values which data structure do you recommend?

For eg: If the z-order is 2 3 4 5 1 6 7 8 9 10 (index of the Application) and if the user has clicked on the Application 5's window then we need to move 5 to the front and the remaining order should be the same i.e. 5 2 3 4 1 6 7 8 9 10.

If I use vector then rearranging the elements (or copying the values) every time doesn't seem to be efficient. 
If I use deque then push_front has some obvious advantage but again removing the Application from its previous position is the problem.
If I use list then every time we need to search for the element and remove it.
Any thoughts on which data structure is the most efficient for my purpose?

Comment: how many layers do you need to cope with? if its small constant factors may dominate

Comment: For now the no. of layers is not more than 32

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the number of windows is probably going to be minimal, I would probably go with a vector of (smart) pointers, and reorder the vector components. While the complexity is greater than with other alternatives, the actual performance will not be bad, as the constants might dominate the complexity.

Comment: there's no need to reorder as you always take one item and bring it to front. With your arguments I would say - go for list. But actually I believe it is possible to achieve a better performance with vector.

Comment: @Nim, Oleg: I used *reorder* in some general sense. A full reorder is not required, but you most probably don't want to do a single swap either. Then you pull the 5th window to the top, you want the window that was previously on the top to be the second in Z order, you don't want to move it behind windows 3 and 4 in the stack. Ie, the implementation would pull the pointer of the 5th, then move elements 1..4 to positions 2..5 (beware of moving order) and then insert the window that was 5th as first.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is using [boost multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). However, this sometimes gets tricky. You can simulate it by having two structures:

- a list to store the order and values
- a map to map values to list positions

So, you could have something like:

```
typedef std::list<int> pos_list_t;
pos_list_t positions;
std::map<int, pos_list_t::iterator> position_map;
```

Then, each time you have to search and change the positions, you can do something like (simplified, but you get the idea):

```
pos_list_t::iterator pos = position_map[window_number];
// pos takes the list iterator. You can move it to the beginning
positions.erase(pos);
positions.push_front(window_number);
// update the map position
position_map[window_number] = positions.begin(); // iterator of the new position. The beginning.
```

You'll also need some joint initialization:

```
positions.push_back(value1);
positions.push_back(value2);
...
for (pos_list_t::iterator it = positions.begin(); it != positions.end(); ++it)
    position_map[*it] = it;
```

Comment: The `map` is overkill. Since the OP is mapping a prefix of the positive integers, `[1..N]`, to objects, s/he can use a `vector` instead.

Comment: @larsmans, yes, you're right. It depends on the numbers the map can get. But still, just an idea of the structure organization and relationship.

Comment: ..I don't think it's the obvious answer, infact, I'd go as far as to say, it's the most convoluted answer... :)

Comment: :) The more general, then? Yes, for those orders of magnitude a map seems overkill... but maybe tomorrow he or she has to cope with thousands of objects :)

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually going to do is:

1. find element at certain position
2. insert new element at the beginning
3. delete element at a certain position
4. iterate through elements

So if you use list - you are in trouble with 1. If you use map. You are in trouble with 4. 
I would say go for vector which has constant for 1,2 and 4. And use some kind of markers for element which need to be deleted from collection. As you probably are not going to have millions of windows you can perform housekeeping inside vector quite rare, say once in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple linked list would be the most handy here and then sort them according to their z-value.

Answer (score 1):

You get use a map where the key is whatever is needed to identify the window and the value is the position of the window. Let's suppose we use a HWND to identify the window.

```
 map<HWND, int> windows
```

At the beginning you have to initialize the map and set for every window the right position. Ex. windows[0x0002] = 0; windows[0x0003] = 1;
The map will be ordered according to value.
When you have to bring a window to front you just need to switch its position with the 0 order window

```
int temp_order = windows[bringToFrontWindow]; 
HWND front_window = windows.begin().first; // the fist window of the map has 0 z-order
windows[bringToFrontWindow] = 0;
windows[front_window] = temp_order;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use simply `std::list` here, because 1) list iterators never invalidate (unless the object is remove from the list) 2) splcing is constant time (not really important since we are talking small lists).

You could maintain a `std::list<Window*>`, and bundle a `std::list<Window*>::iterator` within the `Window` class (assuming there is some `Window` class which manages a window's resource)